# Can't reach NodeJS microservice through Spring Cloud Gateway + Eureka

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, eureka-js-client

I use a microservices architecture in the backend where I have services created using TypeScript and others using Java. Also I have a Spring Gateway and an Eureka server (both using Spring).

Then, Gateway works fine, Eureka works fine and also others microservices written in Java work fine too. The problem is when I try to reach the TypeScript microservice accross the Gateway.

I have a simple Eureka Server using the annotation `@EnableEurekaServer` in Spring.

Also a Gateway connected to Eureka as client where the yaml has this part:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
      routes:
        - id: ms1
          uri: lb://ms1
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms1/**
        - id: ms2
          uri: lb://ms2
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms2/**
```

With this Gateway I want to have two routes `/ms1` and `/ms2` to access the microservice1 (written in TS) or microservice2 (written in Java).

When I run all services, Eureka is shown like this:
[image]

You can see the `gateway`, `ms1` and `ms2`. But, why Java services has `192.168.8.121` and TS service not?

By the way, the links work ok, every service is routed to the port where exists, Gateway and Java microservice are routed to `<gateway_url>:<service_port>/actuator/info` and TypeScript microservice is routed to `localhost:<service_port>`.

Microservice2 is so simple:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getHi() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hi");
    }
}
```

And also into application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: ms2
```

But TS microservice uses [eureka-js-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client) with this configuration:

```js
this._client = new Eureka({
                instance: {
                    app: 'ms1',
                    instanceId: 'ms1',
                    hostName: 'localhost',
                    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
                    statusPageUrl: `http://localhost:8081`,
                    healthCheckUrl: `http://localhost:8081/health`,
                    port: {
                        '$': 8081,
                        '@enabled': true,
                    },
                    vipAddress: 'myvip',
                    dataCenterInfo: {
                        '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
                        name: 'MyOwn',
                    },
                },
                eureka: {
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8761,
                    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
                },
            })
```

So, my idea is:

- When I hit `<gateway_url>:<gateway_port>/ms1/hello-world` it appears the data from TypeScript microservice.
- When I hit `<gateway_url>:<gateway_port>/ms2/hello-world` it appears the data from Java microservice.

The second one works fine, but the route http://192.168.8.121:8762/ms1/hello-world returns a 503 error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon May 16 19:02:56 CEST 2022
[fa1d8857-5] There was an unexpected error (type=Service Unavailable, status=503).
```

And console says `No servers available for service: ms1`.

So I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something, the name from `eureka-js-client` is `ms1`. The LB is to that service... but it not works.

As I've said, with a Java service works fine, so maybe the problem is the way the service connect to Eureka, the name who uses or something like that? But in the dashboard it appears as `MS1` and `MS2` so I'm confused...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue, it was a weird thing.

My `vipAddress` was not correct. It seems Spring Cloud Gateway checks for the `instance.vipAddress` instead of `instance.app`.

So replacing `myvip` with `ms1` it works perfectly.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem and it took me hours trying to find what's going on, until finally I find this answer. It works! Thank you so much!